# Google Chrome cannot determine or set the default browser

Tags: 12.10, google-chrome

I updated the Google Chrome version, and since Opera has become my default browser.

In Google Chrome, under the default browser settings, it just says:

"Google Chrome cannot determine or set the default browser."

How do I change this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the default browser:

via command line:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

and choose the number correspond to google chrome. Now exit and check the problem will be solved from chrome settings(I noticed that a wired thing happen just when Opera become the dfeault).

via GUI:

Click on the dash button in the launcher and search for 'System info'. Then, open 'System info' and move to 'Default applications' section.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to **System Settings** --> **Details** --> **Default Applications**

And set  Google Chrome as default browser. [image] (here chromium in my default browser)

Comment: But why would that happen in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install galternatives
```

Open the program from the start menu. On the left, you will have options to change:

Select: gnome-www-browser & x-www-browser

and change these to Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In Xubuntu

Go to **Settings** --> **Prefferd Applications**

[image]

In my case it's not resolve the issue so I had to run the command

> $ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
>
> Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
>   ------------------------------------------------------------
>   *0    /usr/bin/firefox    40        auto mode
>   1    /usr/bin/chromium-browser    40        manual mode
>   2     /usr/bin/firefox    40        manual mode
>
> Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

and select 1

Comment: This is similar to Linux Mint MATE: Preferences --> Preferred Applications.

Answer (score 0):

For Flatpak-based Chrome installations (e.g. [Chrome from Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/com.google.Chrome)):

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser com.google.Chrome.desktop
```